# How to use ANTLR4 in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, antlr

I'm trying to install ANTLR4 to work with a Xamarin project. Right now, I'm getting a compile error (unrecognized interface) when I try to include the parser and lexer files in the project.

Here's how I've installed the application.

1. Install Java (version 1.6 or higher)
2. Download:

   `$ cd /usr/local/lib
   $ curl -O http://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.5-complete.jar`
3. Add `antlr-4.5-complete.jar` to `CLASSPATH`:

   `$ export CLASSPATH=".:/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.5-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH"`
4. Create alias for the ANTLR Tool:

   `$ alias antlr4='java -Xmx500M -cp "/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.5-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH" org.antlr.v4.Tool'`

Here's a simple grammar to test with

```
// Define a grammar called Hello
grammar Hello;

options
{
  language = CSharp;
} 

r  : 'hello' ID ;         // match keyword hello followed by an identifier
ID : [a-z]+ ;             // match lower-case identifiers
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines
```

Running the command `antlr4 Hello.g4` from Terminal produces the lexer/parser files for C#. When I now try to copy these files into my Xamarin project, I'm asked to resolve several unrecognized symbols.

What ANTLR package should I install? I tried the 4.3.0 version, but this apparently doesn't define the `IVocabulary` interface (as far as I know, there are no other compile errors). From the description, this version of the package was built using Visual Studio 2010 or newer. What is the correct version of ANTLR/package to use with Xamarin?

Comment: What unrecognized symbols are you getting? I use 4.5.1 without any issues. Xamarin or not, the syntax should at least be correct.

Comment: @Rob When I copy the generated .cs files into my project, I get compile errors such as `The type or namespace name Antlr4 could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS0246)`. I then tried to install version 4.3.0 of the ANTLR package from nuget. This resolved most of the issues, but apparently `IVocabulary` is not supported in 4.3. 

What version of the dlls do you use?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33274271/563532) is one of my previous answers, but it's not specifically for a xamarin build.

Comment: @Rob The ***Lexer.cs file uses `Antlr4.Runtime` among other things. How does the compiler resolve this if no references are added to the project?

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken, it's been a while since I set it up. My project is using `Antlr4.Runtime.dll`

Comment: @Rob What version though? I'm not sure what version to use with Xamarin (recall that I installed antlr-4.5-complete.jar but reference a 4.3 package).

Comment: When I get home in about an hour I will check for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100729/discussion-between-rookie-and-rob).

Comment: I'm using `antlr-4.5-complete.jar` to generate the files, and `Antlr4.Runtime.dll` (Version `4.5.0.0`).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get things to build by installing [this version of the package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Antlr4.Runtime/4.5.0-alpha003). From there, I copied the .jar file into `/usr/local/lib`, and added the `antlr4` commands to my .bash_profile:

- `export
  CLASSPATH=".:/usr/local/lib/antlr4-csharp-4.5-SNAPSHOT-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH"`
- `alias antlr4='java -jar
  /usr/local/lib/antlr4-csharp-4.5-SNAPSHOT-complete.jar'`

One more thing. The target language option should be removed from the grammar file in favor of using a command line argument. You should now be able to generate the .cs files with: `antlr4 Hello.g4 -Dlanguage=CSharp_v4_0`.